# wired Ethernet connection not functioning

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

i am using window 10 in my office and recently i cant connect to the wired ethernet. Each time when troubleshoot, it states that more than 1 protocol is missing and cant be fixed. I tried off the firewall, update the device adapter and run recovery. Still there is not solution. I need my office internet connection badly to do my office work. Please help.

Comment: Have you Googled anything around Windows 10, ethernet not working and missing protocol?

Comment: More generally following up on what Matthew wrote, it's always a good idea to clearly state in your question what research you have done in order to try to solve the problem yourself, and what specific steps you have taken to try to solve the problem. (You can, and should, [edit] your question to include more information.) That shows that you have tried yourself first, and it saves time because we won't be proposing solutions that you have already tried. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) for some further suggestions.

Comment: Have you asked your IT Administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistency in Windows Sockets API also known as Winsock is usually the root cause of this problem. If this is the case, try the following troubleshooting suggestions:

1. Go to an elevated command prompt and enter netsh int ipv4 install and restart your computer.
2. Open command prompt window, type netsh winsock reset and press Enter and restart your computer.

For more troubleshooting tips, you can check this article: http://appuals.com/best-fix-one-or-more-network-protocols-are-missing/